# /bin/sh: ligne 0 : exec: node : non trouvé

Tags: php, laravel, passenger

I use Laravel and I have this issue with Passenger Phusion. The app is online and I can't install any command. One more thing : Other Laravel app work in this server...

```
 [Passenger Phusion] /bin/sh: ligne 0 : exec: node : non trouvé
```

**Backtrace :**

```
in 'bool Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::checkCurrentState()' (Perform.h:238)
in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::waitUntilSpawningFinished(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)' (Perform.h:213)
in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::execute()' (Perform.h:1752)
in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::internalSpawn(const AppPoolOptions&, Passenger::SpawningKit::Config&, Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakeSession&, const Passenger::Json::Value&, Passenger::SpawningKit::JourneyStep&)' (DirectSpawner.h:211)
in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::spawn(const AppPoolOptions&)' (DirectSpawner.h:261)
in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)
```

**Environment variables**

```
USER=root
PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin
PWD=/
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
TZ=Europe/Paris
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
RESTARTSRV=1
_=/usr/sbin/httpd
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.4.46 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_bwlimited/1.4 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.6
```

Somebody can help me ?

I can add more information if needed

Regards

Kévin B.

Edit : I have edited with more informations

Comment: Yeah, please share more details

Answer (score 1):

You need to install node on your machine: https://nodejs.org/en/download/